# adding tabs to my facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, tabs

I am trying to add a new box on the main view of our Fan Page.

And populate it with HTML from our main web server when the user opens the fan-page. **I do not want to create any application and then add it as a tab. I simply want to load contents of the tab from a web page.**

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I simply want to load contents of the
>   tab from a web page.

And the way to do that is to

- Create a Facebook Application
- make it installable to pages
- define the tab URL
- generate FBML at that URL

I'm sorry that you don't *want* to create a Facebook Application, but that's your only option.  The otherwise closest thing is [fb:ref](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/ref) but that's for canvas pages only.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new tab from "Edit page - More applications" and look for the FBML application, add it, and you will be able to use FBML (Facebook markup language) which allows your tab to render HTML or FBML to be exact. You have the FQL as well for Facebook query language, which adds extra API features etc...